# Set up redirects with Apache Server for a website running in Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, .htaccess, tomcat, redirect

I have a centOS machine where there is a website with dynamic pages running on Tomcat (port 8080) and I have installed Apache server on the same machine (port 80) with a load balancer in front of this machine (port 80).

In the httpd.config for the directory I have this settings:

```
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www/html">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all

 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^my-old-page$ /en-GB/Shop [R,L]    
 RewriteRule    "^/en-US/foo\.html$"  "/en-US/Shop.html" [PT]
 Redirect "/en-US/foo1.html" "/en-US/Shop.html"

</Directory>
```

And I have added a file called .htaccess under /var/www/html containing only:

```
RewriteRule ^my-old-page$ /en/my-new [R,L]
```

And after that I have restarted apache

```
service httpd restart
```

However it does not work?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why `.htaccess`? If you have access to the configuration file, you shouldn't be using `.htaccess`.

Comment: well, because I'm a newbie of apache server and every guide says to use the .htaccess file, however I copied RewriteRule ^my-old-page$ /en/my-new [R,L] in side <Directory> tag but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You do not have the `RewriteEngine` directive in neither your configuration file nor the `.htaccess`.

Per the [Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteengine), no rewrite processing is done unless the `RewriteEngine` is set to `On`.

It would benefit you to read the [official guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html) and select the best scenario. You may note that all their examples include the `RewriteEngine On` directive. You may also consider using the much simpler `Redirect` directive.

Comment: The documentation is very handy, but my changes on httpd.conf are still ignored, ie. I added in the bottom of the file RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/en-US/foo\.html$"  "/bar.html" [PT] and nothing happens

Comment: Did you restart apache? Do you realize that this won't change the URL on your browser? Did you remove your `.htaccess` file? Did you try using `Redirect`?

Comment: Yes I restarted apache, does not really matter if the URL does not change because I want to see the target page, deleted .htaccess, added these three instruction at the end of my httpd.conf file Redirect "/en-US/foo.html" "/en-US/Shop.html"

RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule    "^/en-US/foo\.html$"  "/en-US/Shop.html" [PT]    but it is still not working

Comment: What do you mean "at the end of the file". It should be in a context applicable to your particular site. E.g. in the `<Directory>` section you showed in your post. And please don't put code in comments. Edit your original question, saying something like "Edit: I did so-and-so", with the code, and leave only a notice in the comments that you edited your question. Comments are not meant for code.

Comment: just edited my question, unfortunately still no success, I am tempted to change User and think kind of settings, but I do not know what really the value should be

Comment: You are only supposed to have one rule, it seems you have three in your edited version. Also, check the apache error log - maybe the rewrite mod is not installed.

Answer (score 0):

Well the solution depends on what you really need. The **easier**, but **not the best** way it's using "mod_proxy_ajp".

in your http.conf active the following modules:

1. mod_proxy
2. mod_proxy_ajp

and add the following:

```
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from localhost
</Proxy>
ProxyPass       / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse    / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

this configuration tells the apache(httpd) proxy all the request to and special port in tomcat that its by default configured in servers.xml

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" />
```